# Why does git fetch fail with "Could not resolve host: (nil)..." with https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew origin?

Tags: git, github, https

I was unable to install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) (see my [question on apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98455/how-do-i-work-around-a-could-not-resolve-host-nil-error-when-installing/99040#99040)), so I looked at the https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go Ruby script and tried the same commands it runs:

```
$ git init -q
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
$ git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n
error: Could not resolve host: (nil); nodename nor servname provided, or not known while accessing https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Why am I getting this error?

**Update:** (in response to [madhead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/750510/madhead)'s answer)

I get the same problem when I use the URL with **.git** postfixed:

```
$ git init -q
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git
$ git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n
error: Could not resolve host: (nil); nodename nor servname provided, or not known while accessing https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

**Update #2:**

I don't think this was a proxy issue (as suggested in [neil's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/888483/neil) answer).

I tried this again and it worked!

```
$ git init -q
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
$ git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n
remote: Counting objects: 126721, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (59085/59085), done.
remote: Total 126721 (delta 89963), reused 100145 (delta 66623)
Receiving objects: 100% (126721/126721), 19.68 MiB | 702 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (89963/89963), done.
From https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
```

I looked in my `~/.gitconfig` file and discovered I had already defined a proxy. I think that was already there when I had the problem, but to confirm I removed it and got a different error:

```
$ git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master -n
error: Failed connect to github.com:443; Connection refused while accessing https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

My theory is that github or homebrew had some kind of problem that they've since fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me this was related to a proxy issue. When I'm on VPN I need to add

```
[http]
proxy = http://proxy.example.com
```

to my `~/.gitconfig`, and if I'm not on the VPN, this proxy cannot be found.

Comment: I don't think this was the problem. See update #2 in my question.

Answer (score 5):

For those getting this error when NOT behind a proxy:

```
error: Could not resolve host: (nil); nodename nor servname provided, or not known while accessing https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

the solution may be to clear the git proxy settings:

```
$ git config --global --unset core.gitproxy
```

Answer (score 0):

You remote URL is incorrect, it should be `https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git` (**.git** postfixed) instead of `https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew`. You can copypaste URLs from Github UI to prevent such typos.