# Brew Update Error with Git

Tags: git, homebrew

I am running into an issue with running both `rvm use ruby --install --default` and `brew update`. It appears the later issue is the reason why I am seeing the first issue.

Here is the error for `rvm use ruby --install --default`:

```
ruby-2.1.2 is not installed - installing.
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.

Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.1.2.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system......
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-2.1.2',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/connorphillips/.rvm/log/1408816616_ruby-2.1.2/update_system.log
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.'
++ rvm_pretty_print stderr
++ case "${rvm_pretty_print_flag:=auto}" in
++ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
++ case "$1" in
++ [[ -t 2 ]]
++ return 1
++ printf %b 'Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.\n'
Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
Gemset '' does not exist, 'rvm ruby-2.1.2 do rvm gemset create ' first, or append '--create'.
```

I then try `brew update` and this is the error I'm seeing:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

What is the source of the issue/fix it.

Comment: Are you on a VPN or something? You can't connect to github because your machine can't find it. May need to configure proxy settings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290822/why-does-git-fetch-fail-with-could-not-resolve-host-nil-with-https-git

Comment: @mu無 there is a difference between couldn't resolve host and ssl certificates. It means that it can't access to github.com at all

Comment: @cphill If you are behind a proxy, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20371843/1860929)

Comment: Can you run `traceroute github.com` on your command line and post the output?

Comment: @Brennan not on a VPN and git is working when I make pushes to projects. Not sure why that would be an issue with trying to pull anything now

Comment: what's bizarre is that I can run `sudo brew update` and it updates and then I run `brew update` and it says everything is up to date and I don't run into any issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue but was able to resolve it. Every time I tried to run brew update I'd get this error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git/': Could not    resolve host: github.com
>   Error: Failure while executing: git pull --quiet origin     refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master

My issue was that I was using a VPN, but after turning it off it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

It might be a problem with Git. Just try to do this on a terminal:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy 

git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

and restart your terminal or open a new one. Then try brew update again.