# Cannot push to Heroku 'fatal: unable to access..Could not resolve host: (nil); nodename nor servname provided, or not known'

Tags: git, heroku, github

I have a few apps on Heroku, nothing has had this problem but I suddenly have had issues running git.  Now I can't deploy my app to Heroku.  When I run

```
git push heroku master
```

I get the following:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/<herokuappname>.git/': Could not resolve host: (nil); nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

When I run

```
git remote -v
```

I get the following:

```
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/<herokuappname>.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/<herokuappname>.git (push)
```

I've looked up everything.  Please help, thank you.

Comment: Did you checked [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18290822/why-does-git-fetch-fail-with-could-not-resolve-host-nil-with-https-git)  ? It's not heroku-related, but also has issues with not being able to connect to git repo, which seem to be root problem.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Whenever this randomly happens to me, removing and adding heroku again as a remote reference always works.

First check if you do have heroku as a remote.

`git remote -v`

If heroku is present, remove it.

`git remote rm heroku`

Then add it back.

`git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:project.git`

Usually this works with me, try it and let me know what happens.

Comment: Didn't work for me , heroku git:remote -a <project_name> , taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129598/how-to-link-a-folder-with-an-existing-heroku-app did the job.

Comment: Same with me I pulled a repository and I had to add: heroku keys:add first and then do heroku git:remote -a <project_name>

Comment: This method doesn't work on my terminal. $ git push heroku master                                                                                                                                                                         master
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Answer (score 29):

Try this:

```
heroku keys:add
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 10):

```
git remote -v
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:project(full url).git
heroku keys:add
```

These steps worked

Answer (score 4):

Try exiting from the terminal, start a new terminal (comand line) process and go to the appropriate directory and then try to push to heroku master once again.

I had encountered an error similar to yours :-

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.heroku.com/<herokuappname>.git/': Could not resolve host: git.heroku.com
```

I did the same thing as mentioned above and it worked out well for me. I am hoping that it will work for you as well.

Comment: This solved my problem. I was really confused because ping and Chrome worked fine. Apparently my old terminal sessions were using a closed socket (i.e.  `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable had changed).

Comment: @TastyWheat: If it helped, would be awesome if you could upvote my answer. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this issue by logging into heroku with `heroku login`

Answer (score 1):

This error make me mad ! It's happend again and again, tips above doesn't work for me. As u can see on [image: screenshot] I do nothing betwin attemps! It just work or don't, but more often don't !

Answer (score 1):

One of the main causes of that error is simply a bad internet connection, If you come across issues like this, simply changing your internet connection or using a better option fixes this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in the following order

```bash
git remote rm heroku
heroku login
heroku git:remote -a <app_name>
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already connected any other remote from git using ssh then you have to connect heroku remote with ssh only. 
To check how remote connected:

```
git remote -v
```

just remove https remote of heroku, connect again with ssh remote. like:

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:<yourProject>.git
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

1. heroku git:remote -a app-name
2. git push heroku master